# How can I turn off all TCP traffic in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've followed Microsoft's directions to disable updates, telemetry and crash reporting, but VS Code is still talking to the web. It looks like there's something going on in `editorSimpleWorker.js` and `editorWorkerServer.js`, but those are some pretty big haystacks to start combing.

Does anyone know what VS Code is trying to accomplish by talking to the web? Marketplace? `npm`? And how to disable it? I can block the outgoing TCP traffic, of course, but besides that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, two weeks after posting the question, I am pretty confident in making the following statement:

There is no documented configuration option or combination of options that will turn off all web traffic conducted by Visual Studio Code.

At least some of the traffic that I've observed is related to the extensions gallery.

Ultimately, VS Code was built to be online. It is intended to talk to the web. If you are trying to use it in an environment in which such connectedness is discouraged, you will have difficulties of some type or other. Instead, find a different product that better fits your requirements, whatever they may be.

Comment: Microsoft provides a (partial?) [list of hostnames](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/network) it communicates with. Depending on your requirements you might be able to block all or some of them.